Upgrading Quarkus from 3.8.5 to current fails using CLI update utility
I am trying to upgrade an application from 3.8.5 to current version which is 3.11.2.
I am using the quarkus update command via the Quarkus CLI on Windows using PowerShell.
The update script gets stuck processing test resources.  It says not parsing the image/video file because its larger than 10MB.  On the 9th file of the same INFO message it just hangs there...it is stuck.  No warnings or errors, it just hangs.  Why would this update even need to look at test resources?
How can I configure the update tool to ignore tests & files and just update POMs as necessary due to the artifact name changes?
I have tried running the 'quarkus update' tool/script via Quarkus CLI and I was expecting it to run to completion but instead it hangs part way through the process.
